# Añadir efecto ondas Ripple sobre una Imagen en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo un `recyclerView` que contiene imagenes, cada item le tengo asignado `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` pero me encuentro que las imagenes dentro del contenidor el efecto de onda `ripple` se reproduce por debajo de el.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_empty"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/default_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cover_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#5c1b1b1b"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

¿Hay alguna forma de indicar que se muestre por delante de todo, que afecte a todos los elementos del contenedor padre?

Answer (score 0):

**Solucionado**

Para que el efecto onda `ripple` se muestre por encima de las imágenes, como que la propiedad `background` está ocupada para la imágen, se debe usar `foreground` que es la capa superior

```
foreground: para crear un overlay
background: imagen
```

En mi caso a todos los `ImageViews` que se pueden pulsar añado
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`